# How to make Typescript enum with implements interfaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, enums

How to make Typescript enum with implements interfaces

i current has this 2 enum

all `enum ENNAME` keys should only include of `enum POSTAG` keys

```
export enum POSTAG
{
    BAD = 0x80000000,
    D_A = 0x40000000,
    D_B = 0x20000000,
    D_C = 0x10000000,
}

export enum ENNAME
{
    D_A = 'a',
    D_B = 'b',
    D_C = 'c',
}
```

---

is there has any way make something like this??

```
export interface ENNAME
{
    [k: keyof POSTAG]: string,
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make an `enum` extend an `interface`.  The best you can do is set up some compile-time checking of the types to produce a warning if you make a mistake, such as:

```
interface ENNAMEInterface extends Record<Exclude<keyof typeof POSTAG, "BAD">, string> { }
type VerifyExtends<T, U extends T> = true
type VerifyENNAME = VerifyExtends<ENNAMEInterface, typeof ENNAME>; // okay
```

That should compile if the value `ENNAME` has the same keys as the value `POSTAG` (minus `"BAD"`) with string values.  Otherwise, `VerifyENNAME` will give you an error:

```
export enum ENNAME {
  D_A = 'a',
  D_B = 'b',
  // oops, D_C is missing 
}

type VerifyENNAME = VerifyExtends<ENNAMEInterface, typeof ENNAME>; // error
//                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Property 'D_C' is missing in type 'typeof ENNAME' but required in type 'ENNAMEInterface'.
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!